# Como controlar um formulário divido em partes?

Tags: javascript, angular, formulário

Tenho um sistema que possui uma grande quantidade de `<input>`s necessários para montar uma requisição, eles são divididos em 4 partes (componentes), sendo cada parte com uma ou mais subpartes (subcomponentes)

Não quero salvar os dados no servidor aos poucos, o servidor só receberá uma requisição com todos os dados. Então preciso armazenar localmente

Tive duas ideias:

1. Criar um formáulrio para cada componente e subcomponente e emitir um evento quando a mesma estiver concluída que serão ouvidos pelo componente raiz, lá será gerenciado os dados
2. Salvar localmente as pates dos dados em LocalStorage, quando a última etapa estiver pronta, montar a requisição

Observações:

- No modelo 1 será salvo os dados localmente de qualquer jeito, porém isso será feito apena pelo componente raiz, já no modelo 2 isso será feito por cada componente ou subcomponente
- Por ser um formulário muito grande, pode ser que ele não seja totalmente preenchido em um único momento, assim como pode ser necessário começar um novo cadastro, mas mantendo o anterior salvo para finalizar posteriormente

Como fazer esse controle de forma simples e legível? Outras formas são bem vindas

<sub>A dúvida não é como implementar, mas qual implementar</sub>

Comment: Eu não usaria nenhuma das duas formas. Creio que armazenar dados de formulário em `localStorage` não seja uma prática muito sensata, já que os dados _podem_ se tornar vulneráveis (com XSS, principalmente). Já procurou por algo chamado ___form wizard___?

Comment: @LuizFelipe por que da vulnerabilidade a ataques XSS? Não dá pra colocar um form container, ficaria muito difícil controlar os componentes filhos através do pai, além disso se eu criar com o _FormBuilder_ eu teria uma estrutura gigante, de difícil entendimento e manutenção

Comment: Suponha que alguém, por alguma razão, consiga injetar um script no seu sistema (XSS). Essa pessoa pode acessar o `localStorage` a partir daí. Por isso não creio que seja uma boa prática...

Comment: Mas só se eu permitir que a pessoa ijete algum script, se meu sistema está protegido, o LocalStorage também está

Comment: De fato. Mas ainda creio que opções como _form wizard_ sejam mais simples. Já deu uma olhada? :)

Comment: Sim, mas é uma forma não muito simples e pouco legível

Comment: Acho a melhor solução usar algo como ngrx, pra centralizar o estado do seu formulário.

Comment: @EduardoVargas poderia adicionar uma resposta?

Comment: Cara acho um pouco complexo demais para ser uma resposta de stackoverflow. Mas pensa que vc tem uma store que é um estado centralizado e a cada step vc atualiza ele.